# Ado .Net 2.0 driver for Interbase XE version

Tags: interbase

Could someone to explain about Ado .Net 2.0 driver for using Interbase XE version?

Answer (score 2):

Embarcadero provides a driver called DBX ADO.Net 2.0 driver for InterBase (version 15.0). This is used to connect interbase XE and above from ASP .Net application.

But this driver is not supported for numeric data type above 9.

Otherwise its working fine.